# How to get the current time in any location

Tags: android

I have to upload an image and with that i have to send the date and time when the image is uploaded, I am getting the latitude and longitude of the device from which it is uploaded, now i want to get the time and date of that location at that point of time when the image is uploaded.
I do not want to take the date and time from device, Is it possible to get the date and time with the help of latitude and longitude of that place.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the time zone and the current local time for a lat long from webservice by GeoNames http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#timezone.

Demo link http://api.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?lat=47.01&lng=10.2&username=demo

Output Format

```
{"time":"2011-12-28 08:03",
 "countryName":"Austria",
 "sunset":"2011-12-28 16:36",
 "rawOffset":1,
 "dstOffset":2,
 "countryCode":"AT",
 "gmtOffset":1,
 "lng":10.2,
 "sunrise":"2011-12-28 08:04",
 "timezoneId":"Europe/Vienna",
 "lat":47.01
}
```

Register for a username here
http://www.geonames.org/login

Comment: Can you provide me sample code or any example, then it will be more clear to me.

Comment: added in the response. Add your lat long to the demo link and get the response

Comment: Can't i get it without using their webservice.Is there any other way possible?

Comment: theoretically yes, you will have to convert lat long into a time zone using an algo. Try this open source library http://ll2tz.sourceforge.net/

Comment: credits? will this be a problem? **{"status":{"message":"the daily limit of 30000 credits demo has been exceeded. Please throttle your requests or use the commercial service.","value":18}}**