# Google web service to get time by location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the current time in any location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652855/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-any-location)

I've heard of open Google WebServices i.e. for maps, and i wondered is there is anything similar to this for time, currency and other functions of Google. 
Regarding Time i found a similar question, but i want some solution for Commercial use: 
[How to get the current time in any location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652855/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-any-location)
Oh, i want to call it by AJAX (Client Side).

The Idea is to offer a Dropdown-List with some Cities all around the world, once a City is selected the local time in the City should be shown. I had Problems finding an Algorithm to include all the various Summertime-Changes, so this Approach seems easier.

Comment: Linked answer seems sufficient

Comment: Also, you may want to take a look at [Timezone lookup from latitude longitude](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41504/417685)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[***Working Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/FCFHy/1/)

Using the [HTML5 geolocation API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#introduction), you can get the current lat/long coords:

```
var currentPosition;
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    currentPosition = position;
});
```

You can use this to make an [ajax request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get) to [the web service](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#timezone) you mention in your post:

```
$(function(){
    var tzObject;
    $("button").click(function(){
        console.log(currentPosition);
        var dt = "lat="+currentPosition.coords.latitude +
                 "&lng="+currentPosition.coords.longitude +
                 "&username=demo"; //change to your uName

        $.get("http://api.geonames.org/timezoneJSON", dt, function(msg) {
            tzObject = msg;
            alert(tzObject.time + " " + tzObject.timezoneId);
        });
    });        
});
```

This returns a JSON object containing the relevant timezone information. Of course, if you have a set list of cities, it's easy to store their lat/long coords and just use those for the request instead. You will need to get a username to use that web service for multiple requests in succession (using 'demo', there's an hourly limit).

Comment: thanks for the Response, pretty much exactly what i looked for. i just was hoping that there would be a solution by Google.